Sample NDVI time series for points and retaining the unique point ID in Google Earth Engine
In Google Earth Engine, I have a feature collection of points with one column that is the "Feature Index". Now I am extracting time series for every point. How can I retain the "Feature Index" column in the output dataset?
Right now I am using this code.
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2001-01-01', '2022-12-31')); //Specify the date range
var ndvi = dataset.select('NDVI','SummaryQA'); //Select the NDVI band

  
var points = ee.FeatureCollection("xxx/xxx/xxx");


var extraction = ndvi.map(function(img){ 
  var ii= img.reduceRegions({
  'collection': points,
  'reducer': ee.Reducer.first(),
  'scale': 250,
});
return(ii)
  
});
extraction=extraction.flatten();

var columns = extraction.first().propertyNames()
print(columns)

var keys = extraction.first().toDictionary().keys()
var attributes = extraction.map(function (f) {
  return extraction.set('dict', f.toDictionary(keys));
});
print(attributes.aggregate_array('dict'))

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: extraction,
  description:'xxx',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
 }); //safe image as csv```

